# Enforcing tag on EC2 Instance launching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I want to enforce users to launch ec2 instances:

- from specific AMI
- put it in a specific VPC and Subnet
- Use a specific Key pair
- Use a specific security group
- And finally add a tag with a Key and value

The JSON code for doing all WITHOUT a condition statement is working perfectly:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LaunchingInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:AccountID:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:AccountID:security-group/SgID",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:AccountID:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:AccountID:vpc/VPCID",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:AccountID:subnet/SubnetID",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:AccountID:key-pair/KeyPairName",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:*:image/AmiID",
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:*:image/AmiID",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:AccountID:instance/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I am adding the Condition clause as mentioned here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/tags-in-iam-policies.html

```
"Condition": {
     "StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Key": "Value"
      }
  }
```

It gives an error of

```
"action": "ec2:RunInstances",
"resource": "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:AccountID:key-pair/KeyPairName"
```

But the name of the Key Pair is already in the resource list! I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Do you want to require users to add a tag, or have the tag added automatically? For the latter, I like to tag all new instances with the username and accessKey of the requestor for all new instance(s), and I do it using a Lambda that is triggered by CloudWatch events.

Comment: The first. But interesting the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use SCP & TagPolicy if you have AWS Organization :

1. Source Control Policy: to enforce tag usage.
2. Tag Policy : to validate the values that you'll set as policy

For more information see this link : https://repost.aws/questions/QULCbS92i8Twma2yTQfKumSw/how-to-enforce-tags-while-creating-any-kind-of-resource-in-aws